# ¿Cómo ordenar el encabezado de una datatable?

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

Quisiera saber la manera correcta de posicionar los encabezados en un datatable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la imagen los encabezados, no se encuentran al centro de la fila: se desborda.

Tengo este código en css que afecta a las tablas (porque tengo varias):

```
table.dataTable td {
    font-size: 0.99em;
}


table.dataTable tr.dtrg-level-0 td {
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

th,td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table th {
text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable thead th {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #111;
}


table.dataTable tfoot th {
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    *zoom: 1;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

también en javascript asigno por defecto un ancho:

```
{
    data:'',width:'5%'
},
{
    data: 'TotalFecha1', width: '5%',
```

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar por favor el codigo de la tabla para ver que esta fallando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.

Trate de ir agregando los tamaños correctos de las filas para que den igual al tamaño de tabla, ejemplo:

```
  <table style="width: 40%">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10%"></th>
    <th style="width:10%"></th>
    <th style="width:10%"></th>
    <th style="width:10%"></th>
  <tr/></table>
```